# Change postgres password

Tags: postgresql, password, password-reset

I've forgotten my postgres password for my local install (Ubuntu 20.04).

I have postgres installed and running

```
henry@henry-Apollo:/$ service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-08-19 18:16:09 BST; 2 days ago
   Main PID: 1924 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 18895)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Aug 19 18:16:09 henry-Apollo systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Aug 19 18:16:09 henry-Apollo systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

I'm trying to find `pg_hba.conf` based on a couple of posts I've seen that explain a process to reset the password.

```
sudo find / -type d -name "pg_hba.conf"
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

I cannot find the file.  How do I reset the password please.

Thanks

Comment: Check your systemd service file, and see what you got, e.g. `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely won't find it this way:

```
find / -type d -name "pg_hba.conf"
```

`-type d` means you're asking for a directory and this would most likely be something like `pg_hba.conf.d`. So you'd rather look for a plain file:

```
find / -type f -name "pg_hba.conf"
```

Or just don't use the `-type` parameter at all and see what you find then.